# Issue with Clojure 'contains'

Tags: vector, clojure, contains

I am going through some Clojure tutorials using Closure Box, and entered the following code:

```
user> (def stooges (vector "Moe" "Larry" "Curly"))
#'user/stooges
user> (contains? stooges "Moe")
false
```

Shouldn't this evaluate to TRUE ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `contains?` answers the question: "Would calling `get` give me a value that's actually in the collection?"  An important distinction for collections containing `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A vector is similar to an array. [`contains?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/contains_q) returns `true` if the `key` exists in the collection. You should be looking for the "key/index" 0, 1 or 2

```
user=> (def stooges (vector "Moe" "Larry" "Curly"))
#'user/stooges
user=> (contains? stooges 1)
true
user=> (contains? stooges 5)    
false
```

If you were using a hash...

```
user=> (def stooges {:moe "Moe" :larry "Larry" :curly "Curly"})
#'user/stooges
user=> (contains? stooges :moe)
true
user=> (contains? stooges :foo)
false
```

As mikera suggests, you probably want something like [clojure.core/some](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some)

Comment: I see. thanks for your help. What I was attempting to do works when I use a set instead.

Answer (score 14):

This is a common trap! I remember falling into this one when I was getting started with Clojure :-)

[contains?](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/contains_q) checks whether the index (0, 1, 2, etc.) exists in the collection.

You probably want something like:

```
(some #{"Moe"} stooges)
=> "Moe"    <counts as boolean true>

(some #{"Fred"} stooges)
=> nil      <counts as boolean false>
```

Or you can define your own version, something like:

```
(defn contains-value? [element coll]
  (boolean (some #(= element %) coll)))

(contains-value? "Moe" stooges)
=> true
```

Comment: Very nice. This is really useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

contains? support Set, if you use clojure-1.4

```
user=> (contains? #{:a, :b} :a)
true

user=> (contains? (set stooges) "Moe")
true
```