# implementing XOR between two collections in clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, functional-programming

i am trying to learn Clojure--and am very green. i am trying to implement a recursive version of set difference between two collections.

what i was trying to do is first combine both lists, convert the combination to a set to remove the duplicates, then pass the mess back to its self and check to see if the first element of the combined collection are in both input lists. if it is pass the rest of the combined collection back with the original collections and repeat the process... but it always passes back an empty list. I make no assumption that the code is all that good. I am new to functional programming.

maybe I'm not using the logical and correctly? i made a test and common-elms doesn't start out empty but maybe its returning early with an empty list? any  help would be really appreciated. thanks.

```
(defn alone 
([l1 l2]
    (cond (empty? l1) l2
      (empty? l2) l1
      :else (alone (vec (set (into l1 l2))) '() l1 l2)))

([common-elms return-list l1 l2]
    "common-elms = set of common elements
     return-list = list of XOR items 
     l1 = list 1
     l2 = list 2 "
    (cond (empty? common-elms) return-list
          (and (contains? (first common-elms) l1) (contains? (first common-elms) l2))
            (alone (rest common-elms) return-list l1 l2)
          :else (alone (rest common-elms) return-list l1 l2))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, @ivanpierre solution is certainly the best because it actually uses the first property of [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) and leverages `clojure.set`. But your own solution based on recursion is valid though there are some flaws in the code. Modified version below with explanations :

```
(defn alone
  ([l1 l2]
   (cond (empty? l1) l2
         (empty? l2) l1
         :else (alone (vec (set (into l1 l2))) '() l1 l2)))

  ([common-elms return-list l1 l2]
   "common-elms = set of common elements
     return-list = list of XOR items
     l1 = list 1
     l2 = list 2 "
   (cond (empty? common-elms) return-list
         (let [ce (first common-elms)]   ;; see [1]
           (and (some #{ce} l1)
                (some #{ce} l2)))
         (alone (rest common-elms) 
                return-list 
                l1 l2)
         :else (alone (rest common-elms) 
                      (conj return-list (first common-elms)) ;; see [2] 
                      l1 l2))))

user> (alone '(1 2 3 4 5) '(3 4 5 6 7))
(2 6 1 7)
user>
```

1. you have to be aware that `contains?` only works on associative collections like maps or vectors (a vector is an associative collection whose keys are indices). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963193/issue-with-clojure-contains) question. 
   The [documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some) for `some` gives the idiomatic way to test in any type of collection if it contains a given element.
2. in the case where no common element is found  (`:else`), you forgot to `conj` the element to your `return-list`.

Note : The style is more Lispy than Clojurian ; to keep a solution based on recursion you can use a `loop/recur`. Here is a general solution for N lists :

```
(defn xor
  ([l1 l2]
   (loop [l1 (set l1)
          l2 (set l2)
          xor '()]
     (if (seq l1)
       (let [e (first l1)]
         (if (l2 e) ;; l2 is a set, test if e is in l2
           (recur (rest l1) (disj l2 e) xor)
           (recur (rest l1) l2 (conj xor e))))
       (reduce conj xor l2)))) ;; when l1 is empty, add all element left in l2
  ([l1 l2 & more]
   (reduce xor (xor l1 l2) more)))

user> (let [l1 '(1 1 2 3 4 5)
            l2 '(3 4 5 5 6 7)
            l3 '(1 10 11 13)
            l4 '(1 2 11 6 6)]
        (println (xor l1 l2 l3 l4)))

(1 10 13 7)
nil
```

Answer (score 5):

Or even easier, using the `clojure.set` namespace:

```
(defn xor-list [l1 l2]
  (let [s1 (set l1)
        s2 (set l2)]
    (seq (clojure.set/difference 
           (clojure.set/union s1 s2) 
           (clojure.set/intersection s1 s2)))))
```

But it's only the function for two arguments returning a list. This should be enhanced for general case `clojure.set/xor` like `clojure.set/intersection`for any number of set returning a set.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are trying to do this recursively? If that is not a requirement, using the `clojure.set` namespace:

```
(defn xor-list [l1 l2]
  (let [s1 (set l1)
        s2 (set l2)
        i (clojure.set/intersection s1 s2)]
    (seq (clojure.set/union
          (clojure.set/difference s1 i)
          (clojure.set/difference s2 i)))))
```