# Filter map of collection by other collection with UUID

Tags: clojure, uuid

I have the following structure

```
 (def my-coll '{:data (
        {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0", :book/name "AAA"}
        {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c1", :book/name "BBB"}
        {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3", :book/name "CCC"}
    )} )
```

and I want to leave only enters with id from collection, for example for filtering by

```
(def filter-coll '(#uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c1"  #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c2") )
```

I want to get

```
{:data (
        {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0", :book/name "AAA"}
        {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3", :book/name "CCC"}
    )}
```

I filter by single value with UUID such way without problems:

```
(prn {:data (filter #(= (:book/public-id %) #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0") (my-coll :data))})
```

where *my-coll* is my input structure.
But when I try filtering by collection

```
(prn {:data (filter #(contains? (:book/public-id %) filter-coll) (my-coll :data))})
```

I got error

```
contains? not supported on type: java.util.UUID
```

What way I can filter input structure by collection UUID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to switch the argument of `contains?`. Here a slightly more idiomatic version:

```
(def my-coll '{:data
               ({:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0"
                 :book/name "AAA"}
                 {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c1"
                  :book/name "BBB"}
                 {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3"
                  :book/name "CCC"})})

;; Note I'm applying this into a set to have faster lookup.
(def filter-coll (set
                   '(#uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c1"
                      #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3")))

;; Here we use contains:
(filter #(contains? filter-coll (:book/public-id %)) (my-coll :data))

;; Here we use the fact that we can call 'sets' like functions:
(filter #(filter-coll (:book/public-id %)) (my-coll :data))

;; And an even shorter, and equivalent version with comp:
(filter (comp filter-coll :book/public-id) (:data my-coll))
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, for `contains?` arguments the collection should go first and the item you're looking should go second. But even if you swap arguments, this won't work as expected, because behaviour of `contains?` function is [a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963193/issue-with-clojure-contains).

`contains?` functions works only for keyed collections, like vectors (where keys are element indexes), sets (where keys are items in set) and maps. Since `filter-coll` is list, `contains?` will throw exception:

```
user> (contains? '(1 2 3) 1)
IllegalArgumentException contains? not supported on type: clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

Nevertheless, you may look up the needed value in `filter-coll` as follows:

```
{:data (filter #((set filter-coll) (:book/public-id %)) (my-coll :data))}
```

You may even consider defining `filter-coll` as set. Since, elements of `filter-coll` are uuids, set seems to be a good fit here.

```
(def filter-coll #{#uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c1"  #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c2"})
```

And then:

```
{:data (filter #(filter-coll (:book/public-id %)) (my-coll :data))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. First you got the order of arguments to `contains?` wrong. So the collection goes first, then the value.

But `contains?` checks if the collection you pass to it (the first argument) contains a key, not a value that is equal to the second argument you pass to `contains?`, and in the case of lists and vectors those keys are indexes: 0, 1, 2... and so on, so that's useless in your case.

What you want to do instead, is turn your list into a set, and that does it.

```
(prn {:data (filter #(contains? (set filter-coll) (:book/public-id %)) (my-coll :data))})
```